# Azure AD - Tracking a User object with EFCore

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

We've created a server-side Blazor application in C# as our internal company intranet site. We're using Azure AD to authenticate and users are able to log in and use the site no problem.

I'd like to create a users table so that users can set their own preferences inside the application. I was going to create an AppUser object and use the objectidentifier claim from the logged-in AD user as the GUID, but I was wondering if I was recreating something that already exists.

Is there a way to use Azure AD with the built-in identity model? If so, is that even a good idea?

Comment: Never done it, but I've heard [you can create custom data points in MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview)

Comment: Did you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I decided to go a different route, but I have upvoted your answer because it will be helpful for others who want to do something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have to be complicated. You can [add custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users#1-add-roaming-profile-information) for a user directly through the Microsoft Graph API.

**Example:**

You could name this custom property as **Preferences**:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions
Content-type: application/json
{
    "@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    "extensionName":"com.contoso.Preferences",
    "Preferences": "Apple"
}
```

Use PATCH to update it.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions/com.contoso.Preferences
Content-type: application/json
{
    "Preferences":"Apple, Orange",
}
```

Use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,displayName,mail,mobilePhone&$expand=extensions` to get the Preferences value.

Use `DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions/com.contoso.Preferences` to delete this custom property.

Use [batch request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching#first-json-batch-request) to add custom attributes to users in bulk. Have a quick test in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).